# creating a function in function file

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble getting this to work correctly I am trying to clean up my php files and make a function that changes the users password. It works fine if I keep the copied code from the function file under `function setPass` in the `Login_success.php` file. When I copy the working code into the `functions.php` file with a function name `setPass` it does not work I am not getting an error message either. I realize that not using PDO prepared statements is unsafe but I will change it once I get this working. Here is my code for the login_success file and the functions file:

Functions.php

```
<?php
require 'DB.php';

function setPass(){   

foreach($conn->query("SELECT password FROM CLL_users WHERE user_name= '$userCurrent'") as $password1) {

    $old_pass = ($password1['password']);
}
$new_pass = md5($_POST['new_pass']);

    if (md5($_POST['old_password']) == ($old_pass) && ($_POST['new_pass']) == ($_POST['verify_pass'])) {

        $sql="UPDATE CLL_users SET password= '$new_pass' WHERE user_name= '$userCurrent'";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);



        echo "Match";
    } else {
        echo "Not a Match";
    }

}
?>
```

login_success.php

```
<?php
require 'functions.php';
require 'DB.php';
session_start();
session_is_registered(myusername);
$userCurrent = $_SESSION['myusername'];
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="CLL_users"; // Table name 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$dateCreated = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="UPDATE CLL_users SET last_login= '$dateCreated' WHERE user_name= '$userCurrent'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>user</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <LINK href="CLL.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>    


        <form id ="css" action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">

            <label class ="formLabel" for="old_password">Old password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="old_password" id="old_password" />
       <br> <label class ="formLabel" for="new_pass">New Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="new_pass" id="new_pass" />
       <br> <label class ="formLabel" for="verify_pass">Verify new password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="verify_pass" id="verify_pass" />


                    </div>     
            <input type="submit" />
    </form>

<?php 
    $_POST['old_password'] = $old_pass;
    $_POST['new_pass'] = $new_pass;
    $_POST['verify_pass'] = $verify_pass;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    setPass($userCurrent, $old_pass, $new_pass, $verify_pass);
    }
 ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just wondering why would you make a function called valid_email($email) that returns the return variable from the other function filter_var(); seems devious. You might as well just use the filter_var function where ever you wanted to use the valid_email function. Same result, except less code and more readability.

Comment: you forgot to concatenate here: WHERE user_name= '$userCurrent'"

Comment: @user1534664 I am new to PHP and I seen in a video tutorial on "tutsplus.com" thats the method that he used to accomplish verifying an email met the proper criteria to be valid to an extent.

Comment: @user1534664 wrapping php's functions with your own functions is fine, specially if you're going to be using them a lot. And this way he doesn't have to pass the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL constant each time

Comment: That explains alot ;) I'm sort of tired, its 3 AM here so when I read stuff like "the copied code from the function file" I'm like: What copied code. Could you try and organize your code a bit so its more readable?

Comment: @KaeruCT I figured that much out ;) just wanted to point it out so hes sure of what hes doing.

Comment: **Please, please tell me you are not storing passwords without a salt.**

Comment: I havent gotten into stronger encryption methods yet all I am using for now is md5 I am a beginner to PHP I'm still learning.

Comment: Well, I hope your website isn't live then.

Comment: Its just on a test server for learning purposes only

Comment: Again, I hope it isn't live.  If the test server is accessible per the internet, then it's vulnerable to intrusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lays in the sequence of the code. You should try passing $userCurrent as a parameter, try and use this function: (I also fixed a few syntax errors)

```
function setPass($userCurrent)
{   
    foreach($conn->query("SELECT password FROM CLL_users WHERE user_name= '" . $userCurrent . "'") as $password1) {
        echo $password1['password'];
        $old_pass = ($password1['password']);
    }
    $new_pass = md5($_POST['new_pass']);
    echo "<br>";
    if (md5($_POST['old_password']) == ($old_pass) && ($_POST['new_pass']) == ($_POST['verify_pass'])) {
        $sql="UPDATE CLL_users SET password= '" . $new_pass . "' WHERE user_name= '" . $userCurrent . "'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        echo "Match";
    } else {
        echo "Not a Match";
    }
    echo "<br>";
    echo md5($_POST['old_password']);
    echo "<br>";
    echo ($old_pass);
    echo "<br>";
    echo ($new_pass);
}
```

btw,
what the BBQ where you thinking here, lol:

```
  $_POST['old_password'] = $old_pass;
  $_POST['new_pass'] = $new_pass;
  $_POST['verify_pass'] = $verify_pass;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but its still not functioning. Do I have to add the $_POST parameters to the function and if so how would I do that because I tried and I kept getting syntax errors...

Comment: Its a bit difficult for me to see what you're doing. But first of all what you should make sure is that every variable that you're going to use has a value (unless you dont want it to have a value ofcourse). The one problem you had inside your setPass() function was that $userCurrent had no value.

Comment: Thats why I wanted to pass it as a parameter, that way you're forced to  pass the value, which validates you can use it consequently.